# Understand cores and threads

Tags: cpu

Could someone help me to understand how many cores and threads I have?

Is it 4 cores and 2 threads ?

```
~$ lscpu
Architecture:                    x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):                  32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:                      Little Endian
Address sizes:                   36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
CPU(s):                          8
On-line CPU(s) list:             0-7
Thread(s) per core:              2
Core(s) per socket:              4
Socket(s):                       1
```

Comment: you have 1 chip in 1 socket, containing 4 cores, with 2 threads each = 8 threads.

Comment: What is unclear about the numbers you posted? They list exactly what you are asking about.

Comment: @StarCat
I know nothing about it so.....